# PHP replace everything between two symbols with something else

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace the domain name of email addresses, between `@` and `.` with `***`

For example:

```
$email1 = info@mytestdomain.com
$email2 = info@mytestdomain.net
```

Need to be become

```
$email1 = info@***.com
$email2 = info@***.net
```

I know I can use the PHP `preg_replace` function but I'm not sure what regex I need to use in my case. So my question is, which regex should I use in my case to replace everything between `@` and `.` with `***`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Live demo](http://ideone.com/FMzFhA)**

```
$email1 = "info@mytestdomain.com";
echo preg_replace("/(.*@)([^\.]+)(\..*)/","$1***$3",$email1);
```

**Output:**

```
info@***.com
```

Comment: @Thanks a lot, does this also with emails like this? `my.name.prefix@domain.com`?

Comment: @user2028856 I improved it as well, try it at the demo link I've provided

Answer (score 4):

You can use this assertion based regex.

```
$eml = preg_replace('/@\K[^.]+/', '***', $eml);
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xS0iT4/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) also.

```
$email1 = "info@mytestdomain.com";
echo preg_replace("/[^@]+(?=\.)/","***",$email1);
```

**Pattern Explanation:**

`[^@]+(?=\.)` Matches any character but not of `@` one or more times only if the characters are followed by a literal dot.